How to generate DropdownButtonFormField from a list of model?
I got an error when running the follow code:
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<int>>?')
 Widget getDropDownMenu() {
return FutureBuilder(
    future: getOptionList(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        // While the task is happening, show a loading spinner
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        // If there's an error, display an error message
        return Center(
          child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
        );
      } else {
        return DropdownButtonFormField(
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == 0) {
              return 'Please choose an option from the list';
            }
            return null;
          },
     
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border:
                OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          ),
          value: _indicators_field_value,
          items: snapshot.data.map((map) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(map.name),
              value: map.id,
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (v) {
            this._indicators_field_value = v!;
          },
        );
      }
    });

}
The getOptionList() will fetch data from the API and put into a Model.  What I get from calling that function is a list of Model. List<Model>
I've been trying for hours and decide to ask here.

You must specify the type  to ensure that the list you’re using matches the expected type in DropdownMenuItem. To solve this issue, you can do this:
DropdownButtonFormField<int>(  // Changed here
 validator = (value) {
   if (value == 0) {
     return 'Please choose an option from the list';
   }
   return null;
 },
 value = _indicators_field_value,
 items = snapshot.data.map<DropdownMenuItem<int>>((map) {  // Changed here
   return DropdownMenuItem<int>( // Changed here
     value: map.id,
     child: Text(map.name),
   );
 }).toList(),
 onChanged = (v) {
   _indicators_field_value = v!;
 },
);

Or you can use List<DropdownMenuItem<int>>.from(...) like:
items: List<DropdownMenuItem<int>>.from(
  snapshot.data.map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(
    value: item.id,
    child: Text(item.name),
  )),
),


my code is works fine now! thank you.
